# On OS X, is it possible to get the user library directory from pure Python?

Tags: python, objective-c, macos

I'm writing a pure Python library, and for various reasons I would very much like to avoid asking users to install any binary extensions. However, when running on OS X, I would also like to locate the user library directory (`~/Library`) so I can store some configuration data there, and my understanding is that for Very Valid And Vague But Important Reasons the proper way to do this is not by just writing `~/Library` in my code, but instead by asking OS X where the directory is with some code like

```
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,
                                     NSUserDomainMask,
                                     YES)
 objectAtIndex:0];
```

Of course, this code is Objective-C, not Python, so I can't just use it directly. And if it were plain C, I'd just use `ctypes` to call it from Python, but it isn't. Is there any way to make this call from Python, without writing an extension module in Objective-C or requiring the user to install some extension module like `PyObjC`? Alternatively, if I just give up and hard-code `~/Library` like everyone else does, then will anything terrible happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, *it is* plain C under the hood, so you can achieve the same result with `ctypes` module:

```
from ctypes import *

NSLibraryDirectory = 5
NSUserDomainMask = 1

def NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(directory, domainMask, expand = True):
    # If library path looks like framework, OS X will search $DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATHs automatically
    # There's no need to specify full path (/System/Library/Frameworks/...)
    Foundation = cdll.LoadLibrary("Foundation.framework/Foundation")
    CoreFoundation = cdll.LoadLibrary("CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation");

    _NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains = Foundation.NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    _NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains.argtypes = [ c_uint, c_uint, c_bool ]
    _NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains.restype = c_void_p

    _CFRelease = CoreFoundation.CFRelease
    _CFRelease.argtypes = [ c_void_p ]

    _CFArrayGetCount = CoreFoundation.CFArrayGetCount
    _CFArrayGetCount.argtypes = [ c_void_p ]
    _CFArrayGetCount.restype = c_uint

    _CFArrayGetValueAtIndex = CoreFoundation.CFArrayGetValueAtIndex
    _CFArrayGetValueAtIndex.argtypes = [ c_void_p, c_uint ]
    _CFArrayGetValueAtIndex.restype = c_void_p

    _CFStringGetCString = CoreFoundation.CFStringGetCString
    _CFStringGetCString.argtypes = [ c_void_p, c_char_p, c_uint, c_uint ]
    _CFStringGetCString.restype = c_bool

    kCFStringEncodingUTF8 = 0x08000100

    # MAX_PATH on POSIX is usually 4096, so it should be enough
    # It might be determined dynamically, but don't bother for now
    MAX_PATH = 4096

    result = []

    paths = _NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(directory, domainMask, expand)

    # CFArrayGetCount will crash if argument is NULL
    # Even though NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains never returns null, we'd better check it
    if paths:
        for i in range(0, _CFArrayGetCount(paths)):
            path = _CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(paths, i)

            buff = create_string_buffer(MAX_PATH)
            if _CFStringGetCString(path, buff, sizeof(buff), kCFStringEncodingUTF8):
                result.append(buff.raw.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\0'))
            del buff

        _CFRelease(paths)

    return result

print NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask)
```

But the universe probably won't collapse if you just use `~/Library` ;)

Comment: OMG, this is amazing, thank you -- I'm sorry you probably won't get as much rep for this as you deserve! Also, would you be willing to license this code under a permissive open-source license (e.g. MIT or CC0)? It would save me a bit of trouble in reimplementing it :-)

Comment: I'm fine with MIT. After all, it's just an example, there's no rocket science here :)

Comment: @DagHøidahl: I'm aware -- CC-BY-SA 3.0 doesn't work for the project where I need this, which is why I asked :-). (In fact, I'm not aware of a single widely used software license that *is* compatible with CC-BY-SA 3.0. It's a pretty terrible choice for Stackoverflow, in a sense; basically nothing on Stackoverflow that's big/creative enough to be copyrightable can legally be copied into anything but toy personal projects.)